# Метод "lastIndexOf" JS. Считаю не пересчитаю!

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = 'example in string';
str.indexOf('in');              //  8
str.lastIndexOf('in');  // 14
```

Считать умею, но не умею)) Справа налево.. Выходить не 14, а 7. Объясните, как считает метод "lastIndexOf".

Comment: Считает индекс подстроки `in` с конца, а именно в слове *str**in**g*.

Comment: 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 1 3 5 7 9 11 14
 v v v v v v  v
example in string
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^  ^
0 2 4 6 8 10 13 15
```